# What is the atomic radius of chlorine?

Tags: atomic-radius

I'm trying to study for chemistry and there's a question in my book about identifying an element based on its atomic radius. But when I looked up the value for chlorine, I found different answers from different sources:

- [79 pm](http://periodictable.com/Properties/A/AtomicRadius.v.html)
- 175 pm (from the Princeton Review)
- [0.97 Å](https://environmentalchemistry.com/yogi/periodic/Cl.html)
- [175 pm (van der Waals radius?)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chlorine)
- [79 pm](https://images.flatworldknowledge.com/averillfwk/averillfwk-fig07_007.jpg)

What is the correct value?

Comment: According to the environmentalchemistry website, the unit is angstroms (the value 0.97 is equivalent to 97 pm)

Answer (score 7):

There is no such thing as unified atomic radius. An atomic radius is a class consisting of van der Waals radii $R_\mathrm{vdW}$ (steric interactions), covalent radii $R_\mathrm{cov}$, and ionic radii $R_\mathrm{i}$ (and some other as well).

From the recent edition of CRC Handbook [1, p. 9-57]:

> $$
> \begin{array}{llrr}
> \hline
> \text{Element} & \text{Symbol} & R_\mathrm{vdW}~(Å) & R_\mathrm{cov}~(Å)\\
> \hline
> \text{Chlorine} & \ce{Cl} & 1.75 & 1.00\\
> \hline
> \end{array}
> $$

Ionic radii are given for the crystallographic data separately [1, p. 12-12]:

> $$
> \begin{array}{llr}
> \hline
> \text{Ion} & \text{C.N.} & R_\mathrm{i}~(Å)\\
> \hline
> \ce{Cl^{+5}} & 3~\text{(pyramidal)} & 0.12\\
> \ce{Cl^{+7}} & 4 & 0.08\\
> \hline
> \end{array}
> $$

#### Reference

1. Haynes, W. M.; Lide, D. R.; Bruno, T. J. CRC handbook of chemistry and physics: a ready-reference book of chemical and physical data.; **2017**; Vol. 97. ISBN 978-1-4987-5429-3.

Comment: Related: Pyykkö's summary of covalent radii, see [my answer here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/66631/4945).

Comment: @Martin-マーチン - Agreed. I think I've linked to Pyykkö's radii in other questions too.